# Return grouped data from method

Tags: c#, .net, windows, linq, collections

I have a method from which I need to return a group, i.e.:

```
public static MyData BinSearch(MyData searchDate)
{
 // First doing a binary search to get the index

 if (index >= 0)
        {
            return recordList[index];
        }

        index = ~index;

        if (index == 0 || index == recordList.Count)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int newIndex = (((index-1)+index)/2)+1;
        string pointer = recordList[newIndex].TaxDet;

        var groupData = recordList.GroupBy(p => p.TaxDet)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

        var output = groupData[pointer];


        return (output); // Here I want to return a group of data
 }
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IGrouping'    to
>   'ConsoleApplication1.MyData'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

EDIT:

```
public class MyData
    {
        public string TaxDet{ get; set; }
        public string empDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what type is MyData ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are combining `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary`, by doing `groupData[pointer]` you are getting value from dictionary, which is IGrouping. If you need to extract data from grouping, you need 1 more index getter `groupData[pointer][taxDet]`

Probably `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key);` is redundant in this case

Comment: I'm getting the correct result in the var 'Output', but the only thing is now I need to return this result (which is a group) to my main from where I called. I'm having trouble returning it

Comment: what do you mean by group here? If you are going to return a whole group then your method return type is not ok. it should be something like public static IGrouping<string, MyData> BinSearch(MyData searchDate)

Comment: thanks for that, how should it be in the main then: I have the calling function as:  MyData pointNetcom = BinSearch(value);

Comment: I guess you don't need to return IGrouping from BinSearch. Please explain what you are trying to do in BinSearch method. From the first glance you don't need to call ToDictionary method, because GroupBy already groups item by specified key. There is no point to create dictionary out of grouping key again

Comment: In this method I'm doing a search, when I get that key/records. Then I want to go to that key and get the key along with it's records, which would be a group and send these records back to the caller (main).

Comment: What if you change  MyData pointNetcom = BinSearch(value); to   IGrouping<string, MyData> pointNetcom = BinSearch(value); in main?

Comment: Yes, maybe good idea. I can try that. But not in the office at the moment. Give me some time and I will test it. I will post back the results... Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this works, but now I further trouble in my program. I need to drop the groupby idea altogether. I will open another question for that.